# Countdown timer, that continue running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I need to create timer, that will continue running in background state and will update UI after app will enter foreground state.
Most appropriative example for this is QuizClash app: [image]

I have 2 ideas below:

1. **beginbackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler**

   - Create first timer (30 sec interval, non-repeatable)
   - Create second timer (0.01 sec interval, repeatable)
   - First timer will fire [self timeExiped] method, which will show some UI updates
   - Second timer will fire update of ProgressBar on the picture above
   - Wrap it all in beginbackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method

   Doubts: if main timer will expired in background state, UI updates won't be shown(?)
2. **State restoring**

   - Start the same timers
   - Use encode​Restorable​State​With​Coder:​​ to save current timestamp, when entering background
   - Use decode​Restorable​State​With​Coder:​​ to get difference between saved timestamp and now.
   - Invalidate main timer
   - Start new main timer with (remains_seconds - time_difference_seconds)

   Doubts: is it even a viable option, since i have no experience with it and can't try it out for a moment?

If you have any other idea, or can point me out at 2 described above, i'll put a beer, if you ever in Moscow :)

Comment: you can't do UI operations when your app is at background. background task doesn't work for you as it has a time limit around ~30sec if i recall correctly. state restoration seems overcomplicated for this task. why don't you keep the time when the app goes to background and calculate how long your app spent at background when the app goes to foreground again. you can simply write `timeWhenAppGoesBackground` into `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: I don't need the UI to be updated in background, since it meaningless. But yep, NSUserDefaults could be an option for storing timestamps, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the Timer?

If it is to trigger UI changes, there is no point in trying to get it to "run in the background" because there's no UI to update.

With any approach, you will almost certainly want to use timestamps... when the app is returning to the foreground, get the elapsed time since the last timestamp, update your UI as needed, and restart a Timer for foreground activity / updates.

Comment: Purposes of main timer (~30 sec) are: 1. Invalidate second timer, which updates ProgressBar 2. Perform some UI actions as it fires. Purpose of second timer (~ 0.01 sec) is just to update ProgressBar. But I can see your point. I'll try to use timestamps then.

Answer (score 1):

Add an observer for [UIApplicationDidBecomeActive](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622953-uiapplicationdidbecomeactive) to the ViewController containing the ProgressBar in viewWillAppear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: nil, using: self.applicationBecameActive)
```

Put it in viewWillAppear because the applicationBecameActive function should only fire when the viewcontroller containing the progress bar is on the top of the stack when the application becomes active again.

Then in the applicationBecameActive method, determine what the current progress value of the ProgressBar should be, update accordingly, and restart the ProgressBar progressing.

```
func applicationBecameActive(notification: Notification){

    //determine where the ProgressBar should be

    //set the ProgressBar progress value

    //restart the ProgressBar progress value updating

}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer on viewWillDissappear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

Comment: Thought it's not objective-c, there are nice points to app lifecycle and notifications i will consider to use. Thanks!